# Rendering a large records in WPF application

Tags: wpf, performance, scroll, datagrid

I'm working on a project which will render a large of records, abount 1 million rows and 100 columns. Currently, I'm using DataGrid control of WPF but it's very lagging when scrolling. I try to improve many things in it but nothing better.

Does anyone have any solutions for this case? Thank you.

Sample: https://github.com/son11592/large-data-grid/tree/master

[Here is the sample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3mM5.gif)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF - Improve better scrolling DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65988263/wpf-improve-better-scrolling-datagrid) - you made NO IMPROVEMENTS at all

Comment: @ASh I have deleted the previous one, this post I just want to ask a slosution for my case, not a libraries or any tools.